# Firebase throws 403 API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a PWA and I want to implement push notifications with Firebase.
I added the service worker and everything works fine but only on localhost. As soon as I deploy my app to production I get this error:

```
An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Requests to this API fcmregistrations.googleapis.com method google.firebase.fcm.registration.v1.RegistrationApi.CreateRegistration are blocked. (messaging/token-subscribe-failed).
    at main.91388754.js:2:1847448
    at async Jt (main.91388754.js:2:1847128)
```

> FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Requests to this API fcmregistrations.googleapis.com method google.firebase.fcm.registration.v1.RegistrationApi.CreateRegistration are blocked. (messaging/token-subscribe-failed).

the request fails with 403:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests to this API fcmregistrations.googleapis.com method google.firebase.fcm.registration.v1.RegistrationApi.CreateRegistration are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/XXXXX",
          "service": "fcmregistrations.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I read everywhere that I need to have `Firebase Installations API` enabled. Not only I have this API enabled, but I also added all the other Firebase APIs to the key too.
I also added my domain to the Authentication->Settings->Authorized Domains (I'm not using the authentication, but hey, i thought let's try it).
Nothing helps.

However, I noticed that my Firebase project is listing an API key that I've deleted some time ago. And there's no way to change it. Inside the project I have a web-app which also lists an API key - it is different and it is the one i'm desperately trying to make work.
Again - why does it work on localhost but not on the server?
Could it be something to do with HTTPS? On localhost my react app is running on localhost:3000 (no HTTPS), and on the server I have a valid certificate.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few days of debugging, I decided to delete my firebase project from the firebase console and create a new one from scratch.
Then I recreated all the API keys in the console and the Oauth keys and now I have it working.
I cannot say what it was but my gut feeling tells me that I was missing the "FCM Registration API" restriction on my last api key. I remember I added all the restrictions that contain "Firebase" and this one obviously doesn't.